# Is there a CEIL version of MySQL's DIV operator?

Tags: mysql, math, performance

With MySQL

`a DIV b`

is much faster than

`FLOOR(a / b)`.

But I need to round up so I'm using,

`CEIL(a / b)`

It seems strange that there wouldn't be a ceiling version of DIV, but I can't find it. Is there anything undocumented hidden away somewhere? Or any other non floating point way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative:

(a + b - 1) DIV b

Answer (score 2):

For `a > 0` you can write

```
(a - 1) div b + 1
```

Comment: Be careful - what happens if a is 0?

Comment: Thanks, actually (a + b - 1) DIV b would be better I guess.